# Put new line to separate each records in phpexcel

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I have a phpexcel application that prints data coming from mysql database. The problem that I am having is that I can't put new line or new blank row to separate each 30 records retrieve from database. I already used this two codes from google:

```
$num_rows = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow();
$objWorksheet->insertNewRowBefore($num_rows + 1, 1);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->insertNewRowBefore(2,10);
```

But it doesn't add any new blank row in each 30 records. Kindly help me..

```
    $newRow = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow();
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->insertNewRowBefore($newRow+2,1);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setBreak('A'.$newRow,PHPExcel_WorkSheet::BREAK_ROW);
```

Comment: you want to add a blank row isit??

Comment: yes to separate 500 records by 30

Comment: `500 records by 30`?? I didnt get

Comment: I have a minimum of 500 records all but it is separated by attendance per employee so that makes 30 each per month.

Comment: i just incremented the row counter by +2, i got empty row as required.

Comment: I tried that but it does not work for me.

Comment: can you add a bit more code, so that i can understand a bit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92096/discussion-between-niranjan-n-raju-and-newbie-n).